# Grouping elements in array by multiple properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, grouping

I have array like this:

```
var arr = [
{"type":"color","pid":"ITEM_1","id":"ITEM_1_1"},
{"type":"color","pid":"ITEM_2","id":"ITEM_2_2"},
{"type":"size","pid":"DEFAULT_0","id":"DEFAULT_0_1"},
{"type":"size","pid":"DEFAULT_0","id":"DEFAULT_0_2"}
]
```

And I want to make a new array look like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "color",
    "relation":[{"pid": "ITEM_1", "id": "ITEM_1_1"},
          {"pid": "ITEM_2", "id": "ITEM_2_2"}]
  }, {
    "type": "size",
    "relation":[{"pid": "DEFAULT_0", "id": ["DEFAULT_0_1","DEFAULT_0_2"]}]
  }
]
```

Thanks.

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
*Thanks Abrar's answer. I adjust it slightly for grouping the same pid items and get the result I want. But there should be a better way to do this?*

```
const arr = [
  {"type":"color","pid":"ITEM_1","id":"ITEM_1_1"},
  {"type":"color","pid":"ITEM_2","id":"ITEM_2_2"},
  {"type":"size","pid":"DEFAULT_0","id":"DEFAULT_0_1"},
  {"type":"size","pid":"DEFAULT_0","id":"DEFAULT_0_2"}
];

const resultArr = [];
const groups =[];
arr.forEach((data) => {
  let type = data.type;
  let newArr = arr.filter(el => el.type === type);
  let resObj = {
    "type": type,
    "relation": []
  };

  newArr.forEach(el => {
    groups.push({"pid": el.pid, "id": el.id});
  });

            var group_to_values = groups.reduce(function(obj, item) {
                obj[item.pid] = obj[item.pid] || [];
                obj[item.pid].push(item.id);
                return obj;
            }, {});
            resObj.relation.push(group_to_values);

  if (resultArr.map(e => e.type).indexOf(type) < 0) {
    resultArr.push(resObj);
  }
})

console.log(resultArr);
```

Comment: You should mention what you have already tried.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to" tutorial service as oultined in the [help]. the objective is for you to show what you tried that isn't working an others help you fix **your code**

Comment: Trust me, I have tried many ways(ex: reduce & map). Sorry for my clumsiness and thank you for your advice.

Comment: @AnDy If my answer solved the problem then you can mark it as accepted. Will be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactored your code and now it looks like this -

```
const arr = [
  {"type":"color","pid":"ITEM_1","id":"ITEM_1_1"},
  {"type":"color","pid":"ITEM_2","id":"ITEM_2_2"},
  {"type":"size","pid":"DEFAULT_0","id":"DEFAULT_0_1"},
  {"type":"size","pid":"DEFAULT_0","id":"DEFAULT_0_2"}
];


const resultArr = [];
arr.forEach((data) => {
  let type = data.type;
  let newArr = arr.filter(el => el.type === type);
  let resObj = {
    "type": type,
    "relation": []
  };
  newArr.forEach(el => {
    resObj.relation.push({"pid": el.pid, "id": el.id});
  });

  if (resultArr.map(e => e.type).indexOf(type) < 0) {
    resultArr.push(resObj);
  }
})

console.log(resultArr); //resultArr contains your desired output
```

Basically I have filtered out the keys from the array based on the `type` since that has to be unique (as per your desired output). This should be pretty straightforward and won't require frameworks or even jQuery.